# How to to print motherboard and display card info on Mac

Tags: macos

Is there any API on Mac OS X to get the name, chipset, manufacturer info for motherboard, display card and sound card devices ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [system_profiler](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/system_profiler/) command line tool with the `-xml` option to generate XML data for your system configuration and then parse the output of that.

```
$ system_profiler -xml
```

Use [popen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/popen/) to run this from within your code and capture the XML output. Then use an appropriate XML library, e.g. [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/), to parse the output.

Comment: thank you...Is there any other way of doing it..   say using IOKit or any other POSIX calls

Comment: @Anonymous: you may be able to get *some* of this info using IOKit, but why re-invent the wheel ? Apple knows more about its hardware and OS internals than we do, so why not let them do the "heavy lifting" ?

Comment: You are right ...  But ...What if the system_profiler tool is not installed or removed by mistake. If application relies on the system settings to operate  there is a high risk...

Comment: @Anonymous: system_profiler is installed as standard as part of Mac OS X so it's highly unlikely to be unavailable - if you're paranoid though then you can always check for its presence at /usr/sbin/system_profiler and report an appropriate error if it's missing

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find info on the mother board in the system_profiler output. Am I missing something? I'm on a macbook pro 2009

Comment: Under `Hardware` you should see `Serial Number`, `Hardware UUID`, etc. Was there something specific you were looking for?